# Update specific field in all documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB that contains a list of objects. Each object has an array of "updaters" which are objects with a field that I want to update. One of the updaters in that array needs a description updated. How can i update just the descrption of the the updater object, that I know "updaterId" of.

[image]

Update:

It appears to me that setting the flag `multi: true` will do the trick in Mongo 2.2+.

```
db.configurations.update(
  {"updaters.updaterId": "90391154-67BB-452E-A1A7-A07A98B94F86"},
  {$set: {"updaters.$.description": "This tool will prevent users from Unloading Linked Revit files for \"all users\" which causes such Linked File to be unloaded by default when opening project."}},
  {multi: true}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update the description updaterId like this:

```
db.collection.update( {"updaters.updaterId" : updaterId } ,
               {$set : {"updaters.$.description" : "My description"}} ,
               false ,
               true);
```

[image]

Comment: Doesnt this only update a single entry? I have multiple objects with the same updaterId and I am trying to change them all at once. Is that possible?

Comment: For now no. Using $in also it will only update the first id in array.

Comment: So I suggest to you use loop. If your dataset is huge, You can go with mongo bulk update.